# Ajax / Deep linking and Google indexing / SEO - Is it a bad idea?

Tags: ajax, seo, search-engine, googlebot, deep-linking

I'm about to embark on building a music oriented website for a friend's band and I want to build something like [this template.](http://radykal.de/themeforest/stylico/?page=features.html) It uses ajax and deep linking.

My worry is that this site will not be crawlable by Google. Is there anything I can do or can code I can adjust to make it crawlable?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please vote to re-open this question, as I believe I have edited it to make more acceptable. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That template doesn't look crawlable to me.  Googlebot will never find your content.  If I go to the page for the template and view source, then search for "Gigs schedule with filter", I can't find it in the page source.  That is because that particular content is loaded with AJAX and not part of the page source.

That template does not use Google's crawlable AJAX standard with `#!` in the url. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/  Googlebot will not be index the content on your site if you use that template.

Furthermore, there appear that there are some url issues.  I see these two very similar URLS `http://radykal.de/themeforest/stylico/features.html` and `http://radykal.de/themeforest/stylico/?page=features.html`.    As a user, if I visit that second url, I get the content, but I don't see the navigation.  It seems likely that if googbot were to find the content, it would index that second url and use it as the landing page for your visitors.  Missing navigation in that case would not be a good user experience, as users would not be able to navigate your site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not get the missing navigation issue in Firefox or IE (latest versions). What about step 3 in the guide? (I have edited my question). Will that allow me to eventually make it crawlable (after setting up proper snapshot / sitemap)? Many thanks